# Why didn't they use the aircraft earlier?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

At the end of Edge of Tomorrow, Cage and Rita convince the J squad to embark on the gunship to fly directly to Paris. Since they're down to their final "life", we know that it provided a fast and safe transportation to the final battle's theater.

So why did they insist on going by foot to the barrage? We see that this is by far the hardest way to do it, and in fact the entire plan seems senseless (they knew the entire beach is a trap to kill them, so why assume there will be cars available farther inland?). It seems like they could just as easily taken the ship (which doesn't even require a crew) and flew to the Alps.

Comment: *"..they could just as easily taken the ship (which doesn't even require a crew) and flew to the Alps."*  We don't know what fuel they used, or what their range was.  Perhaps they used a fuel that was not easy to obtain and had a range that had them dropping out of the sky before they got to the Alps..

Comment: Because bad writing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Still, that would at least have them passing the beach, which was likely the hardest part of the trip :)

Comment: What @Richard said.  And also they had to convince a crew to come with them, insinuating that extra personnel were needed.

Comment: "Safe transportation"? They were shot down. Hardly safe. And they gunship did require a crew. The pilots were killed when they were shot down.

Comment: They were shot down a few hundreds meters from the Omega, which was probably the most well-defended place on earth (albeit you don't really see that in the movie).
And I seem to recall that at the end they were flying it alone, with even one person to spare to man the gun, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this worked was because it was the *FIRST TIME* it had been done. The mimics were winning each battle because they could reset the day and know what the humans where doing. If they flew in and say killed a Alpha, the day would have reset and the mimics would have known they were coming. So with nothing else to lose (last life) they used their final push with the ship. And yes, they did need a crew because the Omega was HEAVILY guarded and the crew (J squad) barely got them through the defenses.  Also, up until that point in the plot, they didn't have the actual location of the mimic pinpointed.

Comment: I'm not wondering why they needed the crew or why it worked on the LAST attempt. I'm wondering why they didn't try that earlier, when they had to reach a dam in the Alps.

Comment: The better question is, "If the mimics knew Cage was tapping in to their power and lured him into the trap at the dam, why didn't they just bleed him out prior to that as he tried to get off the beach or across the countryside?"

Comment: Indeed, indeed :)

Comment: @Chrismas007 they couldn't just bleed him, they had to do blood transfusion from another human, and in a way that keeps him (Cage) alive, at least for some time. I'm don't think Mimics had enough human medical expertise to do that :) especially in the middle of a fierce battle. Also, prior to the dam they did know it was somebody but didn't know who it was so they couldn't zero in on specific person. They needed to lure whoever it was to see who it is (that provided they can actually recognize humans which judging by the difference in the looks may not be the case).

Comment: @StasM C'mon... It is clear the implications in that scene. Cage gets cut then sees the Alpha across the corridor. He yells, "Finish it!" But the Alpha doesn't move. He looks down at his wound bleeding out and realizes the mimic wants him to bleed out so he grabs his pistol to kill himself. The Alpha knocks the pistol out of his hand. This clearly and strongly implies that the mimics goal was to bleed him out to get enough mimic blood out of his system.

Comment: Even with this doing it on the battlefield would be kind of hard (they have to keep him alive for substantial time, while there's pretty big shooting around) and also until he walked into the trap they probably didn't know whom they have to bleed. After that maybe they knew him (depends on if all Alphas/Mimics keep their memories or just the one triggering the reset) but he never even gone to the battle - he went to the MoD instead.